# How to add sessionDelegate option on SocketManager's config Swift

Tags: swift, socket.io, ssl-certificate, urlsession

I'm tryng to connect to a self signed SSL URL.
But when I add sessionDelegate as option it's not working.

```
import Foundation
import SocketIO
import UIKit
class SocketM: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    static var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"https://localhost:8000")!, config: [.log(true), .secure(true), .selfSigned(true), .sessionDelegate(self)])

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        let protectionSpace = challenge.protectionSpace
        guard protectionSpace.authenticationMethod ==
            NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust,
            protectionSpace.host.contains(Services_Routes.host) else {
                completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
                return
        }
        guard let serverTrust = protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            return
        }
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: serverTrust)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
    }
```

It returns me
Type 'Any' has no member 'sessionDelegate'

When I try :

```
SocketIOClientOption.sessionDelegate(self)
```

Type '(SocketM) -> () -> SocketM' does not conform to protocol 'URLSessionDelegate'

Can someone explain me the problem?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating static variable and passing delegate as "self", you can't use self before initialising object.

If you don't need static object of manager then you can write code as

```
class SocketM: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    var manager: SocketManager?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"https://localhost:8000")!, config:  [.log(true), .reconnects(true), .selfSigned(true), .sessionDelegate(self)])
    }
}
```

**And If you want static manager the**

```
class SocketM: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {
    static var manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string:"https://localhost:8000")!, config:  [.log(true), .reconnects(true), .selfSigned(true)])

    override init() {
        super.init()
        SocketM.manager.config.insert(.sessionDelegate(self))
    }
}
```